# Create waterfall chart in extjs using Column chart

Tags: extjs

I am trying to find if ExtJs has waterfall chart. I didn't find this chart anywhere in ExtJs.
Now, I am thinking if we can create waterfall chart using column chart, we just need to change the base starting point for each column of column chart. Please let me know if we have some attribute or property in column chart that we can change base starting point of each column so that it looks like waterfall chart.

Please share the links.
Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Screen shot of what you're trying to achieve. A Gantt chart?

Answer (score 1):

I use highchart to do it. I think it's OK.

http://jsfiddle.net/jlbriggs/q6ubs